# Getting credentials issue when I try to download the file on server using wget

Tags: linux, download, wget, credentials, cron-task

When I run the below command on server, the server throws invalid credentials issue

```
wget -O output.zip https://example.com/get_xml.php?l=user&p=pwd&file=yyyy-mm-dd-full
```

Comment: Research and try quoting. Like `wget -O output.zip 'https://example.com/get_xml.php?l=user&p=pwd&file=yyyy-mm-dd-full'`

Comment: Try to add some screenshots to better explain your problem. And try to explain it more, for instance you can say when I use this command via SSH I face the issue. Or any other scenarios in which the problem arises. I can also see you've filled the tag of `cron-task`, so are you trying to run this command in a cronjob? In that case its always good to take screenshot of that cron.